# how to pause AsyncTask for asking details from user?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to ask user for some details while doing some work in `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` (showing to user some dialog with choices in UI-thread), and after users choice continue the job in `doInBackground()` with chosen parameters from dialog.

What is a best mechanism of transfer this parameter to `doInBackground()`? How I should pause (and continue) thread doing `doInBackground()` (maybe `object.wait()` and `notify()`?)? Should I use a `Handler` for this purpose?

Comment: Why dont you go for another AsyncTask ? Like after taking user input?

Comment: AsyncTask actually will do database version upgrading... And user will need to specify some data for new columns. Splitting database upgrading to more than one AsyncTask... it seems the result will be not very pretty.

Comment: It seems finally I become to such solution: I will ask all information from user in onPreExecute()...

Comment: Don't do that... just make sure all of the information has been provided before you execute. (`onPreExecute` for example)

Comment: I have posted an answer it will surely help you to get your work done. Thanks :)

Comment: @Prizoff Did you try my solution ?

Comment: @SALMAN I will solve it tomorrow, as now I want to go sleep :) and will mark/post accepted solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would ask user for input before actually starting background task. If this is not possible there are couple possibilities:

1. You can use lock object and do usual wait()/notify() stuff on it. You still need to pass data from UI thread to your background thread though
2. I would use queue to pass data from UI thread to background thread and let it handle all the locking.

Something like this (kind of pseudo-code)

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<BlockingQueue<String>, ...> {
    void doInBackground(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
      ...
      String userInput = queue.take(); // will block if queue is empty
      ...
    }
}

// Somewhere on UI thread:
   BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);
   BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask<BlockingQueue<String>,....>();
   task.execute(queue);
   ....
   ....
   String userInput = edit.getText().toString(); // reading user input
   queue.put(userInput); // sending it to background thread. If thread is blocked it will continue execution
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope my answer will solve your problem surely.

**//DO ALL BELOW CODE IN doInBackground() method of AsyncTask**

```
String userInput="";

        YouActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {


            //SHOW YOUR DIALOG HERE

            }
        });


        while("".equals(userInput))
        {
            YouActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                userInput=editText.getText().toString();//fetching user input from edit Text    
                }
            });

        }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It is not a good idea to continuously loop in a thread, using 100% of CPU. This can be replaced with a simple wait()/notify() pair which will stop waiting thread without wasting resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Callable`, submit it to an `Executor`, the `Executor` will return `FutureTask` then you will wait in a `while` loop until `FutureTask.isDone == true`;

This here is an example http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/futuretask

Comment: This kinda makes things more difficult than it needs to be, IMO.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood I don't disagree with you. Only answered to draw attention to the Executor framework

Comment: I was only talking in terms of this somewhat trivial example... it's definitely worth bringing up for long-term/future operations though. In fact, the `AsyncTask` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) recommends it too :)

Comment: @Alex Lockwood Surely regarding this question the very idea of acquiring user input from doInBackground is very wrong as you have already pointed out in your comment to the question.