# JSch - How to let user confirm host fingerprint?

Tags: java, android, security, ssh, jsch

In an Android app, I am attempting to connect to an SSH server using the JSch library.  The remote server is specified by the user, so I don't know the remote fingerprint in advance.  At the same time I don't want to set `StrictHostKeyChecking` to no as I see in so many examples.

I'd like to get the remote server fingerprint, show it to the user for acceptance.  Is this possible either with JSch or regular Java, perhaps with sockets?

Here's an example you can try, just paste it in the `onCreate` of an Android activity:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        com.jcraft.jsch.Session session;
        JSch jsch;
        try {
            jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.setLogger(new MyLogger());

            session = jsch.getSession("git", "github.com", 22);
            session.setPassword("hunter2");

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
            session.setConfig(prop);

            //**Get a host key and show it to the user**

            session.connect();  // reject HostKey: github.com
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            LOG.error("Could not JSCH", e);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Create a lenient connection, learn what you can about the host, show the user, let him choose, create the strict connection.

Comment: "Create a lenient connection, learn what you can about the host, show the user, let him choose, create the strict connection." — pretty sure that is a bad idea because it means sending credentials to an untrusted remote server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I've found a way to do this.  It may not be the best way but it is *a* way.  Using the `UserInfo.promptYesNo` required [looping at the expense of CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636927/how-to-pause-asynctask-for-asking-details-from-user) while waiting for user response or with the overhead of an Executor/FutureTask/BlockingQueue.  Instead the async thread which executes the connection (since network tasks cannot occur on UI thread) is more conducive to doing this twice - once to 'break' and get the user to accept, second to succeed.  I guess this is the 'Android way'.  For this, the hostkey needs storing somewhere.  Suppose I store it in Android's PreferenceManager, then to start with grab the key from there, defaulting to empty if not available

```
String keystring = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("target_hostkey","");

if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(keystring)){
    byte[] key = Base64.decode ( keystring, Base64.DEFAULT );
    jsch.getHostKeyRepository().add(new HostKey("github.com", key ), null);
}
```

Next, proceed as usual to connect to the server

```
session = jsch.getSession("git", "github.com", 22);
session.setPassword("hunter2");

Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
session.setConfig(prop);
session.connect();
```

But this time, catch the `JSchException`.  In there, the session has a HostKey available.

```
catch(final JSchException jex){

    LOG.debug(session.getHostKey().getKey());
    final com.jcraft.jsch.Session finalSession = session;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                    .title("Accept this host with fingerprint?")
                    .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
                    .positiveText(R.string.ok)
                    .content(finalSession.getHostKey().getFingerPrint(jsch))
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("target_hostkey", finalSession.getHostKey().getKey()).apply();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    });

}
```

After this, it's a matter of re-invoking the Thread or AsyncTask but this time the hostkey is added to the hostkey repository for JSch.

Comment: `BlockingQueue` (or similar approach) is the right way to go. Do not call that overhead! +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

1. When `StrictHostKeyChecking` is set to `ask`, JSch calls [`UserInfo.promptYesNo`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html#promptYesNo-java.lang.String-) with a confirmation prompt. Implement the [`UserInfo` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html) to display the confirmation to the user. Disadvantage is that you cannot customize the message in any way (of course, unless you try to parse it, relying on a hard-coded template).

   The message is like:

   > WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
   >   IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
   >   Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
   >   It is also possible that the -key_type- host key has just been changed.
   >   The fingerprint for the -key_type- key sent by the remote host  is
   >   -key_fprint-
   >   Please contact your system administrator.
   >   Add correct host key in -file- to get rid of this message.

   For an example implementation, see the [official JSch `KnownHosts.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/KnownHosts.java.html).
2. Even before the above, JSch calls [`HostKeyRepository.check`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/HostKeyRepository.html#check-java.lang.String-byte:A-), passing it hostname and the key.

   You can implement that interface/method, to do any prompt you like.

---

Check `Session.checkHost` implementation.

Comment: This is for an Android app, any prompting would have to be asynchronous, so unfortunately the `promptYesNo` wouldn't work here.  That's why I had the `Thread` in the original post code snippet.

Comment: And what's the problem about implementing it asynchronously? If you are not able to implement asynchronous prompting or do not want to do that for any reason, why don't you just collect the fingerprint and abort the connection? Then prompt any way you want/can do. And start a new session with known host key.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to, the `promptYesNo` requires an return value, but to prompt the user on Android would require a separate thread; it's not the same as doing in a console app .  But your last bit has given me an idea about collection will report back later.

Comment: You just stop the thread that runs JSch, relay the prompt to the GUI thread and once user responds, you pass the result to the JSch thread and resume it. You do not need a third thread.